# Why can't a value class wrap another value class?

Tags: scala, class, jvm, language-design

Is there a reason for the restriction that one value class can't wrap another value class?

It seems an obvious thing to want to do, and extends the benefit further down the class hierarchy. If `class B(val x: A) extends AnyVal` can be treated as compile-time-only, and uses class `A` behind the scenes, then it would be nice if `class C(val y: B) extends AnyVal` could do the same. It's implemented transparently as `B`, which is implemented transparently as `A` at runtime in the JVM, so all the efficiency and gc overhead advantages carry over to class `C`.

Why the restriction?

Comment: I am guessing, that it's possible to do, but requires some effort on the compiler side nevertheless. And having such capability isn't really very useful, so, they decided to cut it. You can always do `class C(val y: A) extends AnyVal`, and then, whenever you need something from `B` inside of `C` just do `B(y).doStuff` which is only a tiny bit longer than `y.doStuff`, and isn't any more expensive performance wise.

Comment: *Why the restriction?* To already view this as a restriction would mean that you've concluded that this feature is worth making in to the language but is restricted due to a technical limitation. I'd like to ask, why would you need to do this in the first place? From the language perspective, `B` is *almost* always invisible (unless used in a particular why which causes it not to be), why would you want to further create a wrapper around it? What is the advantage over using `A` directly?

Answer (score 3):

This is an implementation restriction. It's lifted in Dotty:

```
$ dotr
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> case class C1(i: Int) extends AnyVal
// defined case class C1
scala> case class C2(c1: C1) extends AnyVal
// defined case class C2
scala> val x = C2(C1(1))
val x: C2 = C2(C1(1))
```